# MongoExpiredSessionError while inserting large csv data to mongodb

Tags: node.js, node-csv-parse

I am using a CSV parser package to transform a large volume of CSV data and then attempting to store this data within a MongoDB database. Although a portion of the data is successfully saved into the database, I encounter an issue after processing a few hundred records, specifically an error denoted as error_1.MongoExpiredSessionError(). This error seems to indicate a problem with the MongoDB session, leading to an interruption in the data insertion process.

I am running the function from Terminal -> tsc .\importdata.ts -> node .\importdata.js.
Is there a way that I can make the function wait until it uploads all the data to the database?

```
    const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

interface JourneyData {
  Departure: string;
  Return: string;
  'Departure station id': string;
  'Departure station name': string;
  'Return station id': string;
  'Return station name': string;
  'Covered distance (m)': string;
  'Duration (sec.)': string;
}

async function importData() {
  const client = new MongoClient(
    'mongodb+srv://hasan....:.......@clustersolita.2ztdulk.mongodb.net/',
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
  );
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db('CityBike');
  const journeysCollection = db.collection('journeys');

  try {
    await journeysCollection.deleteMany({});

    fs.createReadStream('2021-05.csv')
      .pipe(csv({ batchSize: 100 }))
      .on('data', async (row: JourneyData) => {
        const departureTime = row.Departure;
        const returnTime = row.Return;
        const departureStationId = parseInt(row['Departure station id'], 10);
        const departureStationName = row['Departure station name'];
        const returnStationId = parseInt(row['Return station id'], 10);
        const returnStationName = row['Return station name'];
        const coveredDistance = parseInt(row['Covered distance (m)'], 10);
        const duration = parseInt(row['Duration (sec.)'], 10);

        if (duration >= 10 && coveredDistance >= 10) {
          const journey = {
            Departure: departureTime,
            Return: returnTime,
            'Departure station id': departureStationId,
            'Departure station name': departureStationName,
            'Return station id': returnStationId,
            'Return station name': returnStationName,
            'Covered distance': coveredDistance,
            Duration: duration,
          };

          await journeysCollection.insertOne(journey);
        }
      })
      .on('end', async () => {
        console.log('Data import completed.');
        client.close();
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    client.close();
  }
}

importData().catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Try to remove `await client.close();`

Comment: I removed the await but the same error.

Comment: Not just the await, the complete `client.close()`